# Flutter: initState in custom state full widget not triggered for second time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of data that has id :

```
 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "close",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "car",
        },
```

I show this list in list view with horizontal axis :

```
Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: _categories.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      return Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedCat = _categories.data[index].id;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: (index + 1) ==
                                    _categories.pagination.currentPage
                                ? Colors.red
                                : Colors.white,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              _categories.data[index].title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: CategoryWidget(selectedCat: _selectedCat))
              ],
            ),
```

In CategoryWidget i shows items related to above data :

```
class CategoryWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  const CategoryWidget({@required this.id});

  @override
  _CategoryWidgetState createState() => _CategoryWidgetState();
}

class _CategoryWidgetState extends State<CategoryWidget> {
  Future _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = HomeProvider().getItems(widget.id); // not triggered 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<ItemModel>(
        future: _futureCategory,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data.data[index].name);
                });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But when i taped on each horizontal item:

```
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCat = _categories.data[index].id;
    });
  }
```

And set state is done, `initState` in `CategoryWidget` not triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was clearly mentioned in the State class' [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html).

I think the correct way to do this is to override the didUpdateWidget method in the State subclass.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _getItem();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CategoryWidget oldWidget) {
    _getItem();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  void _getItem() async {
    _future = HomeProvider().getItems(widget.id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`initState()` doesn't get triggered when you re-build state, it only get triggered once and that's when the widget is loaded, the `build` method is what get triggered as you re-build your state.

change your code to this:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   _future = HomeProvider().getItems(widget.id);
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<ItemModel>(
        future: _futureCategory,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data.data[index].name);
                });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How could i fix my problem? @hiwajalal

Comment: Thats your mean i override setState method in child? @hiwajalal

Comment: Thats your mean i pass future to child? ` CategoryWidget({@required this.selectedCat, this.future});` @hiwajalal